# What does &amp;amp;quot; mean?

Tags: java, html

I have in code copied from a website something like this:

```
static SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort(&amp;amp;quot;COM4&amp;amp;quot;);
```

What the heck does `&amp;amp;quot;` mean?

Comment: It's HTML. It's called "entity reference". Google it if that option is avaliable to you.

Comment: Also, it looks like doubly-escaped HTML, and broken as well.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I have to agree with you in both comments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`&amp;amp;quot;` means nothing in java. It's just a bug in markup on the website you are using. Originally author mean something like this:

```
static SerialPort serialPort = new SerialPort("COM4");
```

Comment: Aaah, thank you for ensuring me in my first thought :)

Comment: `&amp;amp;quot;` > `&amp;quot;` > `&quot;` > `"`

Comment: thanks a tone .... another example for reference environment=SENTRY_CONF=&amp;amp;quot;/home/sentry/.sentry&amp;amp;quot; 
environment=SENTRY_CONF="/home/sentry/.sentry";